# Sleep a long running process

Tags: multithreading, macos, cocoa, thread-sleep

I have an app that iterates over tens of thousands of records using various enumerators (such as directory enumerators)

I am seeing OS X saying my process is "Caught burning CPU" since its taking a large amount of CPU in doing so.

What I would like to do is build in a "pressure valve" such as a

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:cpuDelay];
```

that does not block other processes/threads on things like a dual core machine.

My processing is happening on a separate thread, but I can't break out of and re-enter the enumerator loop and use NSTimers to allow the machine to "breathe"

Any suggestions - should `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:cpuDelay];` be working?

I run this stuff inside a dispatch queue:

```
if(!primaryTask)primaryTask=dispatch_queue_create(          "com.me.app.task1",backgroundPriorityAttr);


dispatch_async(primaryTask,^{
            [self doSync];
        });
```

Comment: If your process is too intensive and blocking the event loop, then consider breaking it up into smaller, time-sliced chunks of processing, allowing the thread's event loop to continue to be processed.

Comment: Never sleep. Never.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your processing in NSOperation and set lower QoS priority. Here is a little more information:
http://nshipster.com/nsoperation/

Here is code example I made up. Operation is triggered in view load event:

```
    let processingQueue = NSOperationQueue()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    let backgroundOperation = NSBlockOperation {
        //My very long and intesive processing
        let nPoints = 100000000000

        var nPointsInside = 0

        for _ in 1...nPoints {
            let (x, y) = (drand48() * 2 - 1, drand48() * 2 - 1)
            if x * x + y * y <= 1 {
                nPointsInside += 1
            }
        }

        let _ = 4.0 * Double(nPointsInside) / Double(nPoints)
    }

    backgroundOperation.queuePriority = .Low
    backgroundOperation.qualityOfService = .Background

    processingQueue.addOperation(backgroundOperation)
}
```

Comment: I run this in a dispatch queue with a priority - and that doesn't seem to stop the dreaded "Caught burning he CPU" console message

Comment: Try this code, it supposed to use different mechanics.